# Построение Google Chart после завершения AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax, google-chart

Через AJAX строится таблица в которой выводится перечень банков, а рядом с каждым checkbox в value которого зашит цифровой массив в JSON формате.

Суть такая: когда пользователь выбирает два любых checkbox, через Google Chart строится график на основе массивов, которые берутся из поля value в, checkbox.

Если я не использую AJAX (т.е. через перезагрузку строю таблицу), все работает замечательно.

С AJAX не хочет, но это и понятно, т.к. по логике код Google Chart должен грузиться после завершения AJAX запроса т.е. построения/перестроения таблицы с checkbox.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно загрузить код Google Chart после завершения AJAX запроса?

Прилагаю приблизительный формат таблицы (грузится с AJAX):

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>FIRST</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value=[1,2,3,4,5,6] /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>SECOND</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value=[6,7,8,9,10,11] /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>THIRD</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value=[12,13,14,15,16] /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

И код Google Chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {

 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    if (checked.length == 2) {

        var names = $.map(checked, function(check){
          return $(check).attr('name');
        });

        num1 = names[0];
        num2 = names[1];

        arr_itog_1 = $("input[name=" + num1 + "]").val();
        arr_itog_1 = JSON.parse(arr_itog_1);

        arr_itog_2 = $("input[name=" + num2 + "]").val();
        arr_itog_2 = JSON.parse(arr_itog_2);

        bank1_length = (arr_itog_1.length) - 1 ;
        bank2_length = (arr_itog_2.length) - 1 ;
        bank_max_length = Math.max(bank1_length, bank2_length);
        if(bank_max_length<10){
          numcol = bank_max_length;
        }else{
          numcol = 10;
        } 

        var arr_itog_3 = new Array();

        for(i=0;i<=bank_max_length;i++){
          if(i==0){
            arr_itog_3[i]="Месяц";
          }else{
            arr_itog_3[i]=i;
          }
        }

        var result = arr_itog_3.map(function(element, index) {
          return [element, arr_itog_1[index], arr_itog_2[index]];
        });

        draw_chart(result);
    }
 });
}

function draw_chart(chart_values) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
var options = {
    title: title_graph,
    titleTextStyle:{fontSize:24, italic: 'false',bold: 'false', 
 color:'#000000' },
};
var chart = new 
google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в вашем приведенном коде следующая:

Вы создаете двумерный массив `result` что бы дать это в функцию `drawchart`:

Это первый подмассив вашего двумерного массива `result`:

```
0:"Месяц"
1:1
2:6
```

И как видно два последних значения массива числового типа, И это приводит к ошибке `Uncaught Error: Unknown header type: 1` в скрипте `google chart`. Ошибку может посмотреть в `console`․

А в метод `arrayToDataTable` должен попадать массив у которого значения первого подмассива имеют тип `string`.

Я просто до вызова функции `drawchart` преобразовал эти типы.

Это для примера, вы должны до формирования массива сделать все это.

```
0:"Месяц"
1:"1"
2:"6"
```

Это пример вашего уже рабочего кода:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
   <td>FIRST</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value=[1,2,3,4,5,6] /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>SECOND</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="2" value=[6,7,8,9,10,11] /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>THIRD</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="3" value=[12,13,14,15,16] /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {

 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    if (checked.length == 2) {

        var names = $.map(checked, function(check){
          return $(check).attr('name');
        });

        num1 = names[0];
        num2 = names[1];

        arr_itog_1 = $("input[name=" + num1 + "]").val();
        arr_itog_1 = JSON.parse(arr_itog_1);

        arr_itog_2 = $("input[name=" + num2 + "]").val();
        arr_itog_2 = JSON.parse(arr_itog_2);

        bank1_length = (arr_itog_1.length) - 1 ;
        bank2_length = (arr_itog_2.length) - 1 ;
        bank_max_length = Math.max(bank1_length, bank2_length);
        if(bank_max_length<10){
          numcol = bank_max_length;
        }else{
          numcol = 10;
        } 

        var arr_itog_3 = new Array();

        for(i=0;i<=bank_max_length;i++){
          if(i==0){
            arr_itog_3[i]="Месяц";
          }else{
            arr_itog_3[i]=i;
          }
        }

        var result = arr_itog_3.map(function(element, index) {
          return [element, arr_itog_1[index], arr_itog_2[index]];
        });
        console.log(result);
        result[0][1] = String(result[0][1]);
        result[0][2] = String(result[0][2]);
        draw_chart(result);
    }
 });
}

function draw_chart(chart_values) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
var options = {
    title: 'title_graph',
    titleTextStyle:{fontSize:24, italic: 'false',bold: 'false', 
 color:'#000000' },
};
var chart = new 
google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но мой код рабочий если и таблица и код Google Chart грузятся одновременно, хотя я детально ознакомлюсь с вашими рекомендациями. Но проблема не в коде, а как сделать так, чтобы после того, как таблица построится из AJAX подгрузился код Google Chart т.к. чтбы код понимал уже откуда ему тянуть данные для построения графика.

Comment: Дайте подробный пример как вы делаете это с ajax и я дам ответ именно для этого.

Comment: на сервер документе по запросу формируется таблица (как показано в примере) и возвращается через конструкцию echo <<<HERE  <код таблицы> HERE;

Comment: @Oktu 1) Тебе таблица нужна? или данные в нем? 2) Как ты на фронте получаешь данные из этой таблицы?

Comment: ну в моем случае (я нашел для себя такой вариант) таблица строится уже на серверсайде и через echo <<<HERE <код таблицы> HERE; возвращается на страницу, вероятно это не правильно?

Comment: @Oktu ну тогда после `insert` -а на страницу надо взять значения из таблицы и делать то что я делал.